# Сколько занимает проверка подлинности домена в Certificate Manager в Yandex Cloud

Tags: yandex-cloud

Создал домен и сертификат, использую DNS валидацию, для выпуска сертификата для поддомена.
В интерфейсе Certificate Manager

```
    Create a record in your DNS provider.
Тип
CNAME
Имя
_acme-challenge.upis.MYDOMAIN.pw.
Значение
fpq***********.cm.yandexcloud.net.
```

Использую Yandex Connect для управления DNS записями:

[image: Скриншот добавления CNAME записи]

Прошёл час и проверка всё ещё в Pending.

Сколько занимает проверка подлинности и корректно ли я создал записи?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге всё заняло порядка 2 часов.
Для проверки использовал

```
host _acme-challenge.upis.MYDOMAIN.pw
```

и

```
dig @dns1.yandex.net _acme-challenge.upis.MYDOMAIN.pw
```

Ответ содержал

```
_acme-challenge.upis.MYDOMAIN.pw is an alias for fpq*********.cm.yandexcloud.net.
```

и соответсвенно

```
_acme-challenge.upis.MYDOMAIN.pw. 1800 IN CNAME fpq*********.cm.yandexcloud.net.
```